# Entity Framework document wide optimistic concurrency

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, xaf

I have the following XAF, Entity Framework Classes, so that I can implement
Optimistic concurrency.

However it is possible for two users to edit different sales order lines at the same time, without receiving an error.

How can I implement optimistic concurrency for the whole sales order, so that if a second user makes any change to any line item, the first user will experience an error trying to save?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.Updating;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base;

namespace XafApplication1.Module.BusinessObjects
{
    public class XafApplication1DbContext : DbContext
    {
        public XafApplication1DbContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        public XafApplication1DbContext(DbConnection connection)
            : base(connection, false)
        {
        }

        public XafApplication1DbContext()
            : base("name=ConnectionString")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ModuleInfo> ModulesInfo { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrder>()
                .Property(t => t.RowVersion)
                .IsRowVersion();
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>()
                .Property(t => t.RowVersion)
                .IsRowVersion();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class SalesOrder
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int ID { get; protected set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Aggregated]
        public virtual IList<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
    }


    [DefaultClassOptions]
    [DefaultListViewOptions(MasterDetailMode.ListViewOnly, true, NewItemRowPosition.Bottom)]
    public class OrderLine

    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int ID { get; protected set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual SalesOrder SalesOrder { get; set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will investigate the idea of adding something to the RowVersion set property to alter a property in SalesOrder

Comment: I would just add a LastLineChangeDate on the Order header and update that with the individual line.  That way, the RowVersion would get updated on both records.

Comment: @DanielLorenz  where would you put that code?

Comment: When you load the Line, do an Include(a => a.OrderHeader) and update both at the same time.  Or if it is new, load the header and add the new line to the sub list and update the field there.